# Logo en correo con php smtp

Tags: php, email

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola quisiera saber como puedo hacer  o q linea de codigo colocar para que me aparezca un logo asi como el que adjunte en la imagen, en mi caso la pagina se llama dinervent y solo sale la D no se como hacer para colocar un logo en esa seccion asi como sale la R en ese que pase

Comment: Esto normalmente el servidor de correo lo jala del favicon del dominio que envía el email, de la cuenta asociada (si es google dentro de gmail), etc. Eso no viaja en el mensaje (hasta donde yo sé)

Comment: Ah listo gracias ya le coloco favicon a esa pagina directamente a ver si me sale

Comment: amigo coloque mi icon asi como lo tengo en la pagina iniciar que me lo agarra sin problema y nada, lo estoy colocando de la siguiente forma <link rel="icon" href="/reme/imagenes/rve_32.png">  y la dirección de la imagen esta bien, pero cuando me mando el correo no me llega con la imagen que lo identifica.